# Asp.net core 2.0 authorization through openidConnect method to IDP made in identityServer3

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver3, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to connect a in house SSO server, This SSO has been created using IdentityServer3. It works fine with our existing MVC 5 application. recently we are upgrading our product to ASP.net CORE 2.0.

We are running into issue with authentication process. After lot of digging I found that it connecting our authorization end point; however some how it is failing to connect login.

MVC-5 uses OWIN implementation to connect OpenIdConnect. 
here is URL from MVC-5

```
identity/connect/authorize?client_id=XXXX
&redirect_uri=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&response_mode=form_post&response_type=id_token+token&scope=openid+api&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3dwFuNqQIdG7E9axIWsGRaxqn8Aikv4B839r1HfWPm57n9RZ5Ig8BK-r2WuNclpcGZr0Ch2GThSpZ53ShE1zBESfxrSHts_I2iLYfTCvBa0Kd-uRueov-NpXDJOh39yh_f-h8TMcCXRe9S3cvE2eWp64dqJLJZM8EqBsW77b-keS3SvTB2KU0X7NqW-VGdI2StBn0y4kiWg9mZseGS4chgsA&nonce=636483566187911271.OTVmNDY1NGQtZDgxZS00ZjllLThjYzQtYjVkNGYxMGM5ZGZhZGI4MzMyYjctMTBiNi00OGQ3LThmOWItNGExNTc5OGFiYTA4
```

Asp.net Core uses in built OpenId Connect method.
Here URL from ASP.net core 2.0

```
identity/connect/authorize?
client_id=XXXXX
&redirect_uri=XXXXXXXXXXXXX &response_type=code
&scope=openid%20api
&response_mode=form_post
&nonce=636483740666280555.NDA3ZGRjZDQtNTdjNS00NjFiLTllOTYtMDc0MjE2NzhkMzQ5NmFiMzU0ZTQtMDIxOS00ODI5LWI4NWEtYTRiMDYzMTFmYjJi&state=CfDJ8AqnlI2Cn3FJtTEVow2y5i5Kt7x-JhPHvqlWGUu6jOxJQQiBB53rtgKV7_nXM4zY0MbzFPQUuONdoyEmX61bexqlAmbTmpEnVC5CHkr41q4b6e3_JtWTBaCOa3vT1_vCNNnIS6lQW3RH4nV-SQ5PUyVr2IzMO3feVRrkS-NLnLAuUXyKSR3gk0LtuzESq_xQ0dtdrjnWr5-dbCyOvG0p3vFhlaQeKyT55q2jZyM4sO0T7B524l6ICz2cKEVLdR6VU2RpjqV_UAlwM7i9Mm7yo_kbCBbtaOOZDWjDVj6XDop0YUmYJhMLGnlXWVBjD87vmg
&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0
```

If you notice that ASP.net CORE openIdConnect adding nonce parameters, which is optional as per specification; however, I could not get rid from generating it.
Other issue is State parameter is generating differently.

Any help to make it work with Asp.net Core 2.0 to identityServer3. I did not find any help around the blog community.

Rest assured I am passing the right parameters, all parameters work fine if I use with MVC 5.

Comment: Hi and welcome! I notice you use a lot of `[tag:x]` markup in your question text... there's no real need to do that unless your question is specifically about the tag itself, in which case it probably belongs on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, this is my first post, did not know how things work around here, I am guessing my question is posted and out there to get it answered. or do you think if i have to take any action. I noticed that you removed tag from the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending 5 days.. I finally figure out the problem. It was an underlying implementation change in ASP.net CORE in  `OpenIdConnectOptions`  class.

Please refer [Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1572) that i have raised with Microsoft  Asp.net Security Team.